# Declension of `мать` in plural

Tags: склонение

Can someone show me the declension for мать in all the cases plurals?

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/мать

Answer (score 3):

Well, the only irregularity here is that `мать` - changes to `матер` - and then just a regular suffix added - the same one what we have in `боль`, `тетрадь`, `соль` -  that is, all feminine nouns ending at `-ь`.

Those words traditionally are classified as belonging to the 3rd declension, which in plural has following endings:

- *Nom.* `-и` (obsolete `-я`)
- *Gen.* `-ей`
- *Acc.* `-ей`
- *Dat.* `-ям`
- *Inst.* `-ями`
- *Prep.* `-ях`

This classification is pretty rough though, and Russian linguist Zaliznyak came up with a more [precise classification](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C:%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0) which is de-facto pretty much adopted by the linguistics community.

According to this classification, word `мать` belongs to `8e^` category, where:

- the number eight corresponds to the 3rd in traditional classification
- letter `e` indicates that for any case except nominative the suffix is stressed, not the root
- the `^` symbol indicates that this particular noun still has some kind of peculiar properties. In our particular case, it's exactly `мат` → `матер`  transformation.

By the way, there's other example of **8e^** - `дочь` in plural becomes `дочери`.

What can stop you from asking a question about declension of any Russian word you are interested in? **Refer to [the Russian wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)** (this information quite often is omitted in the English one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Им.ма'тери
Род.матере'й
Дат.матеря'м
Вин.матере'й,
Тв.матеря'ми,
Предл.о матеря'х.

That's the declension of the word мать(singular)– матери (plural ).